# Reading from a text file to multiple arrays OR classes in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

So I am relatively new to c# and coding in general and I was hoping you could help me out.

So I had found earlier in another topic, how I can save to a 2d array from a text file BUT I have been given a task where it would be best if the file I was reading from could be split into multiple arrays. Here is what I have so far (please be gentle):

```
public void Importer()
{
    String input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ballots.txt");
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    ballotHolder = new int[r, c];

    foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
    {
        c = 0;
        foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            if (col == "A")
            {
                counter++;
                VoterBallot holder + ("counter") = new VoterBallot();<-- just an idea that does not work..
            }
            else
            {
                //ballotHolder[r, c] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
                c++;
            }
        }
        r++;
    }       
}
```

The text file will be formatted like this:

```
A A
1 2 3
3 2 1
3 1 2
A A
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4
4 2 3 1
1 3 2 4
B B
```

As it stands reading into one array with the first block is simple BUT I cannot figure out how to save the text blocks into SEPARATE arrays. The "VoterBallot" class just contains a public 2d array called "ballotHolder"... There is a simple answer to this I am sure of it, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any help any one can offer would be AWESOME!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the file format at all. What do the letters represent? Why two of them? What do the numbers represent? What is the significance of the columns and rows?

Comment: What structure are you wanting? What does VoterBallot look like?

Comment: sidenote: instead of `String input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ballots.txt");` you can use `string rows = File.ReadAllLines(...);` and then do `foreach (var row in rows)`.

Comment: I agree with Jonesy, you have to give more info regarding how the parsing should be made. Have you seen `List` or `Dictionary` and given them a though, instead of using `int[][]`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the whole file as a string, and then splitting that string into multiple lines, and then splitting those lines into multiple arrays, what if you read the file one line at a time and then decided (based on the line you just read) which array it should go into?

Some documentation on reading line by line:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx

Comment: for this question, that doesn't really change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```html
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\ballots.txt");
var list = input.Split('\n');
var matrix = new Array[list.Count(), 1];

int i = 0;
foreach (var element in list)
{
    var strings = element.Split(' ');
    matrix[i, 0] = strings;
    i++;
}
```